# How to use Google Cloud Shell with the new Windows Terminal

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, windows-terminal

I just want to SSH into my compute instances using a profile in the new Windows Terminal app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nvm, I found out you can add a commandline argument to the profiles section. For anybody else trying to figure this out:

```
{
       "guid": "{*add_a_guid*}",
       "name": "Google Cloud Shell",
       "commandline": "ssh -i *path_to_ssh_key* *username*@*ip_address*",
       "icon": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\cloud_platform_logo.ico",
       "hidden": false
}
```

You can generate a guid in PowerShell using this command:

```
[guid]::NewGuid()
```

Comment: That assumes that SSH is already authenticated. But my default Google Shell is at  C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\cloud_env.bat""       But I cannot seem to set up that Batch file in Windows Terminal It comes up with C:\program  not recognised.

Comment: @user2129049 I must say just set up SSH regularly before going about this and setting it up as a profile in the terminal. The other problem you seem to be facing stems from the fact there are spaces in the path you are providing and unless such a path is "covered in double quotes", the path is only read up to the first space. And so, C:\Program is what the path has become. Use double quotes and that'll solve that problem.

Comment: I end up using the Visual Studio example, which is also under programs File. So   "commandline": "cmd.exe /k "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/cloud_env.bat"",
"icon": "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\cloud_platform_logo.ico",   Works for me in getting the Google SDK shell open under Terminal

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:
`"commandline": "cmd.exe /k \"C:/Users/**YOUR_USER**/AppData/Local/Google/Cloud SDK/cloud_env.bat\""`.

Remember about escaping backslash.

Comment: Yes ... Basically copy and paste from the Google Shell's shortcut (right click ==> Properties).

Answer (score 6):

Easiest and neat way to do this by running Linux WSL 2 like Ubuntu, install `gcloud` sdk, then setup gcloud by running `gcloud init` and use below config in Windows Terminal:

```js
{
  "guid": "{d8567bf5-f802-498a-899a-efedc99a2aa8}",
  "hidden": false,
  "name": "Google Cloud Shell",
  "commandline": "wsl -d Ubuntu-20.04 gcloud beta cloud-shell ssh",
  "fontFace": "Cascadia Code PL",
  "useAcrylic": true,
  "acrylicOpacity": 0.6,
  "backgroundImage": "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\.terminal\\.gshell-icon.png",
  "icon": "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\.terminal\\.gcloud-icon.png",
  "backgroundImageStretchMode": "none",
  "backgroundImageAlignment": "center",
  "backgroundImageOpacity": 0.5,
  "tabColor": "#1a73e8",
}
```

> **Note**: In the command:
>
> `wsl -d WSL-NAME gcloud beta cloud-shell ssh`, you can use any wsl
> like (kali-linux, alpine, openSUSE-Leap-15.2, etc. just make sure you
> install and setup gcloud sdk)

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me:

```
  {
    "guid": "{c79dfc7a-3346-4dd3-b6c0-c0107e319a95}",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "Google Cloud",
    "commandline": "powershell.exe -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\google-cloud-sdk\\platform\\PowerShell\\GoogleCloud\\BootstrapCloudToolsForPowerShell.ps1\"",
    "icon": "%USERPROFILE%\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Cloud SDK\\cloud_platform_logo.ico"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, work for me: First at all, add "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK" to windows path, then add to Windows Terminal JSON file this:

For cmd:

```
{
        "guid": "{9f8bb872-db3d-4398-9571-a983a22ff18e}",
        "hidden": false,
        "icon": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/supercloud-16x16.ico",
        "name": "Google Cloud SDK Shell",
        "startingDirectory": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK",
        "commandline": "cmd.exe /k cloud_env.bat"
    },
```

For powershell:

```
{
        "guid": "{9f8bb872-db3d-4398-9571-a983a22ff18e}",
        "hidden": false,
        "icon": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK/supercloud-16x16.ico",
        "name": "Google Cloud SDK Shell",
        "startingDirectory": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Cloud SDK",
        "commandline": "powershell.exe -NoExit -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:/cloud_env.bat"
    },
```